# How to create a FULLTEXT index for two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I have two tables that look something like this:

Table #1:

```
CREATE TABLE iteminfo
(Code CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY,
Tags TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Table #2:

```
CREATE TABLE items
(ID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Code CHAR(1),
FOREIGN KEY (Code) REFERENCES iteminfo(Code));
```

I want to create a FULLTEXT index using the fields Name and Tags from the two tables. I would assume that I will have to use EQUIJOIN or something similar but this doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE items JOIN iteminfo WHERE items.Code = iteminfo.Code
ADD FULLTEXT (Name, Tags);
```

I want to know:

Is this even possible to do?
If yes, then how do I do it?
If no, then what other ways are there to index two columns present in different tables?

Thanks for answering in advance! I apologise if this question already exists but I couldn't find the answer online.

Comment: an index cannot be applied across tables columns

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

But... It would make sense to collect the various columns from the various tables together in a single column and apply a `FULLTEXT` index to it.

Assuming there are many tags for each `item`, you could initialize such via:

```
CREATE search_info ( PRIMARY KEY(name) )
SELECT name,
       CONCAT(name, ' ',
           ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tags) FROM iteminfo
                      WHERE code = items.code ) ) AS search
    FROM items;
```

Then

```
ALTER TABLE search_info ADD FULLTEXT(search);
```

(After that, changes to `items` or `iteminfo` would need to also modify `search_info`.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try what you have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I tired what was suggested in @RickJames's answer and it seems to be the solution to my issue. For anyone else who might want to know, here's what I did but in context to the information I gave in my original question:

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD COLUMN Tags TEXT;

UPDATE items
SET search = CONCAT(name, ' ', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tags) FROM iteminfo WHERE code = items.code))
WHERE Code IS NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE items ADD FULLTEXT(Tags);
```